# Why filter function is returning array even when it does not pass the condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I'm struggling to understand why this code is not working. its working with a small dataset though.

```
const gl = wList.GreateLeague
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./raw/data.json"))
    
(function () {
  let glFinds = data.pokemons.filter((poke) => gl.hasOwnProperty(poke.pokemon_id))
  let ax = glFinds.filter((p) => {
    return gl[p.pokemon_id].stats.filter((ammo) => {
      return (
        p.attack === ammo[0] && p.defence === ammo[1] && p.stamina === ammo[2]
      );
    });
  });
  console.log(glFinds)
  console.log(ax)
})();
```

my output for both console is same, therefore filter on ax is not working.
ax is working fine if I include `testData.json` which is a smaller then `data.json`.

edit: stats look like this. here [0],[1],[2] are the attack defense and stamina

```
"stats": [
          [1, 15, 15, 20.5, 1494],
          [0, 13, 11, 20.5, 1494],
          [2, 14, 15, 20.5, 1494],
          [0, 10, 15, 20.5, 1494],
          [1, 12, 11, 20.5, 1494],
          [0, 15, 15, 20.5, 1494],
          [3, 13, 15, 20.5, 1494],
          [0, 14, 10, 20.5, 1494],
          [2, 15, 14, 20.5, 1494],
          [0, 11, 13, 20.5, 1494]
        ],
```

my data files have array of objects like this:

```
{
      "pokemon_id": 155,
      "attack": 2,
      "defence": 5,
      "stamina": 0,
      "move1": 209,
      "move2": 125,
      "level": 4,
    }
```

I am trying to filter any object that matches (0,1,2 index) of stats array, object's attack, defense and stamina must match any of the stats array first 3 element.

Comment: _"Why filter function is returning array even when it does not pass the condition"_ - Because that's how `.filter()` works. It will always return an array. Either empty or the elements passing the predicate.

Comment: _"...why this code is not working"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_; _"its working with a small dataset though."_ - Are we supposed to guess what the data is? What the difference to the "big" one is?

Comment: i provided more info, let me know if its sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The function inside `filter` must return `true` or `false`, depending on whether the current item shall be included in the output array or not. But your function returns `gl[p.pokemon_id].stats.filter(...)`, which is an array, as Andreas already pointed out.

When trying to evaluate an array as `true` or `false`, it counts as `true` (even if it is empty), therefore your whole `filter` procedure effectively does nothing.

```js
if ([]) console.log(true);
// true
```

Comment: @Achintvishwas _"all the return statements are returning boolen value..."_ - No. Heiko even mentioned the one `return` that does not return a boolean.

Comment: And what's the solution to OPs problem? Mentioning the problem is a start, but that's not really an answer/solution.

Comment: you word made my day. now its working. problem was as you point-out. that line is returning an empty array. that's why filter was not working. thank you man.